# how to Vue.set with item id instead of index

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i have realtime application what i am doing get available data from backend and save as array.
when user click its going to unavailable sending index to backend its broadcast to all users who is in current page and hide unavailable data.

```
var vm = this;
      this.$echo.channel("accept-coin").listen("AcceptCoin", response => {
        vm.$set(vm.coins, response.indexid, response.coin);
        vm.coins[response.indexid].result = response.result;
        vm.$auth.fetchUser();
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.coins[response.indexid].hide = false;
        }, 10000);
      });
```

problem is if current array have 5 objects for example and 2 hide unavailable when new user open this page he will have only 3 objects

if user who have 5 objects in array if click 5th object. its working on current user but other who have 3 objects in array getting error.

what i actually want that i want to modify object with item id instead of index

Comment: Then you should use either plain Object or Map instead of Array.

Comment: thanks another option i found `findIndex` option for do this job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple solution i found that use `findIndex` methods

```
var vm = this;
      this.$echo.channel("accept-coin").listen("AcceptCoin", response => {
        var indexid = vm.coins.findIndex(f => f.id === response.coin.id); //<-- this find index with coin id so then i can do whatever 
        vm.$set(vm.coins, indexid, response.coin);
        vm.coins[indexid].result = response.result;
        vm.$auth.fetchUser();
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.coins.splice(indexid, 1);
        }, 10000);
      });
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It is slower than if you used a plain Object as a hashmap, or the ES6 Map - if the speed is a factor for you.

Comment: how can i optimize it?

Comment: `findIndex` uses a linear search - always starts from the first array element and sequentially going to the end. This means O(n) complexity. With an Object or Map you can leverage an O(1) because they use hashing to instantly get you the key/ID you are looking for. For the case with plain Object - your Object will have keys/properties with the ID of each coin - and the value of the key will be the corresponding coin. So you can simply use `myObject[response.coin.id]`

Comment: Yes seems u are right when 2 user love when 3rd user come between code recieve instant error page won't run